# Pass list of complex object to sql query and filter in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How to pass a list of complex object and search in sql.

Ex: Just say I have following list

```
 List<Paziente> patients = new List<Paziente>
    {
        new Paziente{ Cognome = "Dehan", Nome = "Cooray"},
        new Paziente{ Cognome = "Paul", Nome = "Luca"}
    };
```

Then say I have Paziente sql table. So how to write a sql query to search Cognome and Nome for **list of objects.** from Paziente sql table

Sql Table "Pazinete" contains Cognome and Nome columns

Comment: Pass your object as json and use the built-in openjson functionality.

Comment: @Stu my sql server versions is 2012 , But OPENJSON support SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later. I

Comment: What do you mean by pass list of objects? Where do you pass them from? What is the need for passing to SQL server? What is the actual source? Probably a direct SqlBulkCopy from source is better if you really need to pass it to Sql server. Once in SQL server, you would do plain SQL queries. If you don't need to pass really and say you are using C# for this, then you could simply do a Linq query.